# Finding the highest grossing day in history

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following relevant columns in my 'orders' table:

`Date_Day` (is a range from 1 to 31 with no trailing 0)

`Date_Month` (is a range from January to December, not numerical)

`Date_Year` (is the year in 4 digit format, ex: 2005)

`Total` (number with 2 decimal places)

I know the way of storing date is absolutely awful, but this was the database I was given. I am trying to find a few things and I'm not sure if there is a way to do it in SQL instead of doing the math in PHP:

1. The SUM of each day of each year.
2. The SUM of this day last year
   (where this day is the nth weekday of the month. So for today, it
   would be the 1st Tuesday of October in 2012)
3. The highest grossing
   day in history

MySQL is not my forte, and while I can figure it out in PHP, I would love to see it done in MySQL so I can start to learn it more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to keep your database structured as it is, you could use these queries:

The SUM of each day of each year:

```
SELECT Date_Year, Date_Month, Date_Day, SUM(Total)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY Date_Year, Date_Month, Date_Day
```

The SUM of this day last year:

```
SELECT SUM(Total)
FROM tablename
WHERE
  Date_Year = YEAR(CURDATE())-1
  AND Date_Month = MONTHNAME(CURDATE())
  AND Date_Day = DAY(CURDATE())
```

The highest grossing day in history:

```
SELECT Date_Year, Date_Month, Date_Day, SUM(Total)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY Date_Year, Date_Month, Date_Day
ORDER BY SUM(Total) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Very cool, thank you. One more thing, what if I wanted the SUM of this day for all previous years. I've looked at auto incrementing on the WHERE, but am at a loss.

Comment: @Greg-J for the sum of this day for all previous years you could use `SELECT SUM(Total) FROM tablename WHERE Date_Year < YEAR(CURDATE()) AND Date_Month = MONTHNAME(CURDATE()) AND Date_Day = DAY(CURDATE())`

Comment: Hi fthiella, I don't feel I explained myself properly. I apologize. I'm not trying to get a daily sum of all previous years on this day combined. I want to return the sum of each day's Total for this day on all previous years. So I would have a sum for 2012, 2011, 2010, etc. 

Thank you so much for all of your help so far.

Comment: @Greg-J okay no problem :) this one should be correct, you need to add a GROUP BY: `SELECT Date_Year, Date_Month, SUM(Total) FROM tablename WHERE Date_Year < YEAR(CURDATE()) AND Date_Month = MONTHNAME(CURDATE()) AND Date_Day = DAY(CURDATE()) GROUP BY Date_Year, Date_Month`

Comment: Thanks so much fthiella! I just noticed that we're getting this month/day from prior years which isn't actually what we want to get. For instance, October 4th is the first Friday of the month this year, but last year it was the first Thursday. It is much more relevant for me to get the information based on the nth weekday of the month instead of the precise date. Is that even possible?